What is the proof that $\{ \varepsilon \}^+ (Kleene plus) = \{ \varepsilon \}$
So the proof that $\{ \varepsilon \}^* = \{ \varepsilon \}$ I understand, however I don't get why $ \emptyset ^+ = \{\} $ but $ \{ \varepsilon \}^+ = \{ \varepsilon \}$. because if the definition of $\Sigma^+$ is $\Sigma^+ = \Sigma^* \backslash \{ \varepsilon \}$ then if $ \Sigma^* = \{ \varepsilon \}^* $ then shouldn't $\{ \varepsilon \}^+ = \{ \varepsilon \}^* \backslash \{ \varepsilon \} = \{ \varepsilon \} \backslash \{ \varepsilon \} = \emptyset$ right? But everywhere I look it is just given as an example without proof.

I think your problem is with the kleene plus definition. You can see here a correct definition of kleene plus: if $\Sigma$ is your given language, it's the union of all the $i$-th power of $\Sigma$ with $i=1,2,...$, so:
$$\Sigma ^+ = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \Sigma ^{i}$$
where $\Sigma^{i}$ is defined recursively as $\Sigma^{i}=\Sigma.\Sigma^{i-1}$  if $i=1,2, ...$ and $\Sigma^{0}=\{\varepsilon\}$. Note that $.$ is the concatenation of languages which has $\{\varepsilon\}$ as the identity element (if you're familiar with algebra, this might be helpful, otherwise just ignore it).
Instead, the definition of kleene star is the same but with $i=0,1,2,...$ as index of the union, so the union contains the term $\Sigma ^0 = \{\varepsilon\}$. This means that

If $\varepsilon \in \Sigma$, so if the language already contains the empty string, then both $\Sigma ^+$ and $\Sigma ^*$ contain the empty string $\varepsilon$ and $\Sigma ^+ = \Sigma ^*$
Otherwise, if $\varepsilon \notin \Sigma$, then $\Sigma ^*$ contains $\varepsilon$, while $\Sigma ^+$ doesn't

So, for your case,
$$\{\varepsilon\}^+ = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \{\varepsilon\}^{i} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \{\varepsilon\} = \{\varepsilon\}$$
because for each $i=1,2,...$ we have $\{\varepsilon\}^{i}=\{\varepsilon\}.\{\varepsilon\}^{i-1}=\{\varepsilon\}^{i-1}$ recursively until we reach $i=1$ and $\{\varepsilon\}^{1}=\{\varepsilon\}.\{\varepsilon\}^{0}=\{\varepsilon\}^{0}=\{\varepsilon\}$

You are confusing alphabet and language. The empty string does not belong to the alphabet.

@J.-E.Pin that’s right, fixed it, thanks
